# Policy file for OSGi conditional admin service?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to configure Felix 5.6.1 to only install bundles signed with a particular key. So far I have only been successful in detecting the compromised authenticity of bundles.

If am not mistaken this should be done using **BundleSignerCondition**

The example from "OSGi in action":

```
ALLOW {
 [ org.osgi.service.condpermadmin.BundleSignerCondition  "CN=core,O=baz,C=de" ]
 ( java.security.AllPermission "*" "*" )
} "Signed by core"
```

Do I presume correctly the service needs a specific configuration file, containing these permissions ?

Or should it be enforced programmatically, as shown in the book ?

[UPDATE - 11th January 2017]

I've installed the bundle **security_policy_ch14-1.0.jar** built by the code in Chapter 14 from https://github.com/mcculls/osgi-in-action. This is the Github repository of the book's source code. The bundle parses a policy file as described and puts the permissions in effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be done programmatically. But you could write code which reads a "policy file" and then makes the proper method calls.